# How can I check for gender value by NameID?

Tags: java, jsp

I have this code that checks duplicate name id

```
NameRefBean myNameBean = new NameRefBean();
myNameBean.load(NameID);
if (!myNameBean.getErrFlag()) {
    errExistFlag = true;
    errCode = DUPLICATE_NAME_ID;
    return(false);
```

I have switch case where it saves data from the jsp page form

```
case ACTION_SAVE:
    if (hdTxnType.equalsIgnoreCase("Add")) {
       if (validateInputData()) {
        nameBean.setNameID(tbNameID);
        nameBean.setName(tbName);
                    nameBean.setGender(tbGender);
        hdTxnType = new String("Update");
                }
            } else {
                nameBean.setNameID(hdNameID);
                nameBean.setName(tbName);
                nameBean.setGender(tbGender);

            }
            break;
```

My question is how can I check for gender value when particular `nameid` is selected?  If user changes gender value from M to F, I need to give a warning on the jsp page saying "gender already exist do you want to modify it?"

Here is my jsp page

```
<% if (nameBean.getErrFlag()) {%>
    <CENTER><b><font color=red><%= nameBean.getErrMsg() %></b></font></CENTER>
<% } %>

<TABLE WIDTH="800" BORDER="0">

  <TR>
    <TD><B>Name ID: </B></TD>
<% if (nameBean.getTxnType().equalsIgnoreCase("Add"))
   { %>
    <TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="tbNameID" VALUE="<%= nameBean.getnameID()%>" ></TD>
<% } else { %>
    <TD><%= nameBean.getNameID()%> </TD>
<% } %>

    <TD><B> Name: </B></TD>
    <TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="tbName" VALUE="<%= nameBean.getName()%>" ></TD>

    <TD><B>Gender: </B></TD>
    <TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="tbGender" VALUE="<%= nameBean.getGender()%>"  ></TD>
  </TR>

<BR>

  <TR>
<%  if (userProfileBean.hasRole("FULL") ) { %>
    <TD>
    <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT NAME="action" VALUE="Save Changes">&nbsp;
<% if (nameBean.getTxnType().equalsIgnoreCase("Update"))
   { %>
    <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT NAME="action" VALUE="Delete">&nbsp;
<% } %>
    <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT NAME="action" VALUE="Cancel">&nbsp;
    </TD>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a piece of JavaScript that print the warning, if a user changed the gender. The only thing you have to do then, is to enable this java script if the nameid is already set (then the name already exists, and every change should print the warning.)  If the nameid is null, then it is a new name and you must not enable the java script warning functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your help but could you tell me how can i add javascript and do that in my jsp page.. i have added jsp page above